# Does disabling unused languages [Python ASP.net CGI Perl] in PLESK8 Speed Up PHP5 on Apache server?

Tags: php, asp.net, python, apache, plesk

Fellow Folks,

Inspecting om my PLESK 8.2 on APACHE2 with PHP 5.2.3 I saw this. Being a person who loves peed, **would I gain anything by disabling all the stuff except PHP? which is the only thing I use really?** I'll do anything to speed up my site. Advise in regards to the buttons in this picture is appreciated greatly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - disabling the other language's won't make PHP any faster, as the other options won't be using CPU time unless they're actively being used.

In theory, you *might* save some memory due to Apache modules not being loaded, but this is pretty marginal.

That said, if you're not going to use them it makes sense to disable them anyway.